# IWbemLocator->ConnectServer hanging when called from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, com, window, wmi

I am using this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer

To get WMI Queries working. It works fine as part of a console app but when I move the code into a function and call it from DLLMain the ConnectServer function never returns.

I have tried running the function in another thread.

Seems this is an issue that others have run into: [IWbemLocator ConnectServer call never returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343966/iwbemlocator-connectserver-call-never-returned)

Are there any gotchas with using COM Server from DLLs?

Comment: You should not call WMI in DllMain, DllMain is a very special function https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873

Comment: Hi Simon. I do not call WMI from DLLMain. I call a function upon PROCESS_ATTACH which then handles the WMI processing.

Comment: "when I move the code into a function and call it from DLLMain the ConnectServer function never returns"... you call it from DllMain, directly or indirectly, that doesn't matter

Comment: Ah I see, how can I use the WMI functionality from a DLL? Also, do you happen to know the reason that we cannot simply call from DllMain?

Comment: Read the links.

Comment: @jongjena [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices)